# Python: KeyError When Searching by a Value in One Column in Another Column That Has The Values Contained Between # Signs

Tags: python, split, keyerror

I am trying to find if values in one column (Column_A) are contained in another column (Column_B) that have values that are separated by # signs. Then I would like to return the matching value in a new column (Column_C).

The data looks like this:
[image]

I have tried this:

```
def find_matching_value(row):
    a_values=[float(x) for x in row[my_df1.Column_B].split('#') if x !='']
    if row[my_df1.Column_A] in a_values:
        return row['Column_A']
    else:
        return None

my_df2['Column_C']=my_df1.apply(find_matching_value, axis=1)
```

However, I get a key error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['#16.990000#16.990000#16.990000#28.990000#28.990000#16.99#16.99#16.99#21.99#21.99#21.99,\n'#13.490000#13.490000#13.990000#11.99#11.99#12.49', \n'#13.490000#13.390000#14.490000#16.990000#16.990000#17.490000#12.49#12.49#12.99#15.99#15.99#15.99'dtype='object', length=3)] are in the [index]"
```

Not sure what is causing the issue here.

Comment: Can you show your expected output ? Does the column `Column_C` needs to hold all the matching values or a single one ?

Comment: The expected output would just be a single value for each row in Column C:
16.99
11.99
12.49

Comment: But then, `Column_C` will be the same as `Column_A` ?

Comment: In the example it would but may not be the case for subsequent rows.

Comment: All right, I posted an answer below that may address your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) here, you can slighty ajudst your *listcomp* :

```
my_df1["Column_C"] = [a if any([b == str(a) for b in lst]) else None
                      for a, lst in zip(my_df1["Column_A"],
                                        my_df1["Column_B"].str.split("#"))]
```

Output :

```
print(my_df1)
​
   Column_A                                                                                Column_B Column_C
0     16.99  #16.990000#16.990000#16.990000#28.990000#28.990000#16.99#16.99#16.99#21.99#21.99#21.99    16.99
1     11.99                                                    #13.49#13.49#13.99#11.99#11.99#12.49    11.99
2     12.49                #13.49#13.39#14.49#16.99#16.99#17.49#12.49#12.49#12.99#15.99#15.99#15.99    12.49
```